# Mobile Google Tag Manager modify version without resubmitting

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to figure out GTM for mobile.
It says on the documentation:

> Developers can use the Google Tag Manager interface to implement and
>   manage measurement tags and pixels in their mobile applications,
>   without having to rebuild and resubmit application binaries to app
>   marketplaces.

However, if I want to add new tagging/property, I need to download the new version of GTM-xxxx.json? What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your app ships with a version of your container, and you should definitively update the container you ship with your app when you update your app. But the TagManager service will update that base container with the latest published version when available automatically on the back.

The update may take some time due to connectivity in mobile apps, but once updated it is stored in cache and used in future instantiations of the app. You should expect some users to have the base version of the app until the service had a chance to update.

Comment: thanks. once you publish, how long should we expect until the changes go live?
I tried creating new version, download the container, and publish the changes. It's been few hours but it still not in effect. It works when I do preview though.

Comment: It should be instantaneous if the app is online.

Comment: do you have to delete the old version from the container once you publish a new version? I'm seeing the app still uses the old version even though I published a new version and updated the .json within the bundle.

Comment: @ordinaryman09 did you able to solve the reinstallation issue? I am facing same issue.